# Не удалось разрешить ресурс в конструкторе

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

После одной из загрузок проекта с использованием `MaterialDesign` и `CalcBinding` в VS19 начались проблемы - а именно конструктор грузится очень долго, и после загрузки выдаёт подобное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно работать невозможно, ведь интерфейс в дизайнере начинает выглядеть как ванильный, без применения стилей `MD`, ошибки `CalcBinding` выглядят вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом проект компилируется и работает нормально, но пилить интерфейс становится невозможно. Как это исправить?

Comment: Очистите его и пересоберите. Также советую руками удалить obj и bin директории (ну и весь мусор). Это помогает со многими проблемами с XAML редактором.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ удалил obj и bin, директории, очистил и перестроил проект, однако после этого ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, я нашел ответ на этот вопрос, необходимо:

- Очистить кэш VS
- Создавать интерфейс в конфигурации AnyCPU
- В настройках проекта целевую платформу `AnyCPU` и поставить галочку "Предпочтительна 32-разрядная версия"
- Использовать конфигурацию Release
  Лично мне помогло и использование `Release` и смена конфигурации